# No deviceToken received when sending a Push from Parse to my App

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform

I´m trying to implement Parse in my App, but everytime I send a Push Notification from Parse to my App, the deviceToken field is marked as "undefined". I followed all the steps from the Parse tutorial to implement Parse, but I don´t receive any Pushes (even if they are marked as Sent in Parse).

I made a blank project to see if Parse worked or I was doing something wrong, but in the blank project everything went OK (I followed the same steps as before).

That´s why, I think that there could be something wrong in the AndroidManifest, even if I´m not sure....

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="eu.sabbatic.activities.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="eu.sabbatic.activities.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />





<application
    android:name=".PaoPaoApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:noHistory="true" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.InfoTicketActivity"
        android:label="@string/titulo_info_ticket" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.AddTicketActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.AddKmActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >

    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".api.services.ApiRetrofitSpiceService"
        android:exported="false" />
    <service android:name=".queue.FileUploadTaskService" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ImageFullActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_image_full" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ProjectListActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_proyectos_asignados" />

    <provider
        android:name=".util.PaoPaoContentProvider"
        android:authorities="eu.sabbatic"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.crashlytics.ApiKey"
        android:value="405bbabdc6154694194b8ccd87e0443c46534530" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
    </activity>


          <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
          <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
               <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
               </intent-filter>
           </receiver>
            <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
                android:exported="false">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
            <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="eu.sabbatic.activities" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


</application>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Parse.initialize(this, "EDpscncFFdc8o30B2GA9BL6YlCMxbqzfomP17bKY", "XOU25E6bPqIGRCZq4ikHhlv7DpkQcqW7wCWKHQ9J");
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            String deviceToken = (String)    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().get("deviceToken");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with notification, In my case the Installation  tabled was used  both for IOS and android. Because IOS was already in use and all the fields were created as per IOS requirement once all the fields are created on Installation table, one can't add additional fields to the table, and I was getting

> D/ParseHelper(13425): ParseUser.becomeInBackground subscribeInBackground fail This user is not allowed to add a field to _Installation. You can change this setting in the Data Browser.

This was because Parse register you to GCM and when it does that it comes with additional field `deviceTokenLastModified` . But there is no field to accommodate this in your Installation table.

The solution is to go to Data Browser > Security > Setting > Change permission mode to advanced and select the addField permission.

Once you add this field you can go back and revoke this permission.

The other thing I noticed in your code is you are initializing  Parse in your activity this is not recommended, you should do it in your Application class.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering! I think that this is not the problem I have, as I already have the "deviceTokenLastModified" field too, even if it is always marked as "undefined" too. I followed all the parse tutorial, but these two fields aren´t being filled and when I launch the app, it is stopped automatically....

Answer (score 0):

Is `eu.sabbatic.activities` your package name?
Is it written in?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="eu.sabbatic.activities" >
```

I think the package name really matters to receive pushes.

Also in your parse account go into push and watch how much pushes were really sent. And check the target of the push.

[image: Parse push]

Comment: Yes, the package name is correct. When I go into Push, I see that there were 0 Pushes Sent, even if it is marked as sent (in green) and before sending the Push the device was detected correctly. That´s why I have no idea what could be happening...

Thanks for answering, by the way ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have encounter this also. But I noticed that when I install my app into Real Device deviceToken has keys on it but when I try to run it in Genymotion deviceToken is "undefined".

Solution is:

What emulator do you use?

If you use Genymotion.
The problem was that Genymotion doesn't come out with google apps which means you can't use the GCM.  In order to fix it you should follow this guide (very easy) [Installation ARM Translation in Genymotion](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952)

If you use Real Devices.
I have no idea what is wrong. Maybe someone can answer into this side